# Generating (inline CSS) HTML templates from Flask not working

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

For a personal website I would like to randomly select a background picture (out of 4) for my starting page using flask. When try to create a HTML template (with inline CSS for formatting), the resulting HTML does not display the picture chosen at random.

So far I have tried to use url_for(), as I thought the problem might be that jinja cannot find the files, but this does not resolve my problem.

I also looked at the whitespace and delimiters, which seem to be correct in my mind.

## The code from my app.py:

```
flask import Flask, render_template
import random
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    intt =  random.randint(1, 4)
    random_number = ("../Images/artwork/{}.jpeg".format(intt))
    return render_template('index.html', random_number=random_number)
```

## The code in my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: "Pretoria Gross";
    src: url("../Fonts/Pretoria.ttf");
}

ge {
    color:  Yellow;
    font-family: Pretoria Gross;

    font-size:70px;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;

    background: url('../Images/artwork/{{random_number}}.jpeg') no-repeat top center;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size:  25% auto;
}
</style>

<a href="about.html">
  <ge>Website<br/>Title<br/>here</ge>
</a>
```

The resulting HTML does not render the CSS. Where do I go wrong? 
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`random_number` is already storing the desired path. Change `url` in the css:

```
background: url('{{random_number}}') no-repeat top center;
```

Or, you can simply pass `intt` to the template, and keep the original css templating:

```
return render_template('index.html', random_number=intt)
```

Comment: Hi Ajax1234, thank you for your comment. You are of course correct, the above code would not make sense, I have tried both inserting the path and just the random number - but the issue remains. The error I get when I run the app is: 

"GET /Images/artwork/3.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 -

"GET /Fonts/Pretoria.ttf HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Sorry this is my first post, I will try to be more careful next time!

Comment: @secretsanta Hmm. Have you placed your images directoy in a `/static/images` folder in your main project directory? `flask` automatically searches in `/static/images` folder for all images. As such, your url would become: `/static/images/random_val.jpeg`

Comment: I did not! Fantastic it works now. Thanks for your help